# Getting yahoo error on my laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome

On my Laravel facing an issue on server. On post request of ajax, on browser alert once show me an error of max_var_limit and then showing following error.
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
        <style>
            /* Copyright (c) 2010, Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved. Code licensed under the BSD License: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/license.html */
            html{color:#000;background:#FFF;}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:text-top;}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}legend{color:#000;}

            html { background: #eee; padding: 10px }
            img { border: 0; }
            #sf-resetcontent { width:970px; margin:0 auto; }
                        .sf-reset { font: 11px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; color: #333 }
            .sf-reset .clear { clear:both; height:0; font-size:0; line-height:0; }
            .sf-reset .clear_fix:after { display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; }
            .sf-reset .clear_fix { display:inline-block; }
            .sf-reset * html .clear_fix { height:1%; }
            .sf-reset .clear_fix { display:block; }
            .sf-reset, .sf-reset .block { margin: auto }
            .sf-reset abbr { border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; cursor: help; }
            .sf-reset p { font-size:14px; line-height:20px; color:#868686; padding-bottom:20px }
            .sf-reset strong { font-weight:bold; }
            .sf-reset a { color:#6c6159; }
            .sf-reset a img { border:none; }
            .sf-reset a:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
            .sf-reset em { font-style:italic; }
            .sf-reset h1, .sf-reset h2 { font: 20px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif }
            .sf-reset h2 span { background-color: #fff; color: #333; padding: 6px; float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
            .sf-reset .traces li { font-size:12px; padding: 2px 4px; list-style-type:decimal; margin-left:20px; }
            .sf-reset .block { background-color:#FFFFFF; padding:10px 28px; margin-bottom:20px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 16px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 16px;
                border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;
                border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;
                border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
                border-right:1px solid #ccc;
                border-left:1px solid #ccc;
            }
            .sf-reset .block_exception { background-color:#ddd; color: #333; padding:20px;
                -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 16px;
                -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 16px;
                -moz-border-radius-topleft: 16px;
                -moz-border-radius-topright: 16px;
                border-top-left-radius: 16px;
                border-top-right-radius: 16px;
                border-top:1px solid #ccc;
                border-right:1px solid #ccc;
                border-left:1px solid #ccc;
                overflow: hidden;
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            .sf-reset li a { background:none; color:#868686; text-decoration:none; }
            .sf-reset li a:hover { background:none; color:#313131; text-decoration:underline; }
            .sf-reset ol { padding: 10px 0; }
            .sf-reset h1 { background-color:#FFFFFF; padding: 15px 28px; margin-bottom: 20px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
                -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
                    <div id="sf-resetcontent" class="sf-reset">
                <h1>Whoops, looks like something went wrong.</h1>

            </div>
    </body>
```

Why it is showing an error of yahoo. I also checked laravel log file that is saying DB query error and $xyz field is not found even that field query is not anywhere in the project that shown in log file.

I am trying to understand the relevance of the error. Because issue is max_var_limit log file saying field missing in some uncoded query and browser alert saying yahoo error. Anyone could brief  the actual issue and reason behind this please.

Comment: _"and browser alert saying yahoo error."_ - what "alert" are you talking about? The only mention of Yahoo is in the copyright notice in the `style` element content - and that doesn't mean whatever error you are having, has anything to do with Yahoo.

Comment: you should change app debug to true in env so that you can check the exact error

Comment: @CBroe I think OP has posted the source code of the page that he says is alerted. No code about what is causing the issue (expecting laravel code)

Comment: This is the default error page in case of fatal error with an exception that cannot be handled. Nothing to do with Yahoo. I believe, Symfony did copy some CSS from Yahoo at some point and had to add their copyright.

Comment: Thank you all. I have found the error that was about some variable that is solved now. But still looking for the alert prompt with yahoo comment. Actually have to answer to client for that why alert mentioned yahoo even though there is no service used by yahoo in project. That's why looking for the actual reason of that.

Comment: There: *Laravel default exception: https://github.com/illuminate/exception/blob/master/resources/plain.html#L7

Comment: @Alfizamalek about which variable.?

Comment: In code there were some error for variable in query result

Comment: @Alfizamalek I can't find explicit explanation since, basically, no one was interested in it. But I'm 90%+ sure that this piece of CSS that does reset the default CSS has been wrote by Yahoo and published under **BSD** license that _require_ Laravel to add their copyright. That's it.

Comment: This is the CSS under license I'm talking about: http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css